# Prevent Slickgrid from reordering the DOM elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, firebug, slickgrid

I have 5 checkboxes on Slickgrid with the HTML like so:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

So if I run a css selector - `input[type=checkbox]` on Firebug, the first element in that list of elements is the first one (as expected)

Then if I select the first checkbox, the HTML for that element(the first checkbox) gets a new attribute `checked="checked"`. But slickgird now shoves is the element at the bottom of the list, but maintains the styling.

So now when I run the same CSS selector `input[type=checkbox]` , the first element in that list of elements is the SECOND checkbox, which visibly looks incorrect.

SO question is how do i prevent slickgrid from doing that.

Comment: Works for me? http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/qk5Ra/

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firebug but the selector should return all of the listed elements. `input[type=checkbox]:nth-of-type(1)` Should return the first input even if it is checked.

Comment: Does it matter that SlickGrid is being used?

Comment: @Amey If you've got access to Google Chrome you could right-click the element and inspect - which should give you the correct type of element even if it has been replaced by any JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of slickgrid. If a user takes an action on the first element, Slickgrid inserts that row to the bottom of the list but keeps the styling as before.